# Codename One Windows Phone Build Fail

Tags: windows-phone-8, codenameone

I'm experiencing problems while building my Codename One project for Windows Phone.
I've had 3 attempts: 2 failed and 1 was stuck on a build phase for more than an hour and I decided to cancel it.
I've downloaded error logs for both failed attempts (files were more than 60M and I've noticed it too late, so sorry for using your server's bandwidth). Here is the extract (files sizes are more than 60M) from the last error log (`2f361a99-589d-4e29-9e6d-14d22b1cacc3-1453240937030-error.txt`/`Tue Jan 19 2016 23:46:42 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)`):

```
Executing: java -Xmx1024m -jar win_xmlvm.jar --in=C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\build6825805865501307423xxx\classes --resource=C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\build6825805865501307423xxx\ApplicationCN1\ApplicationCN1\res/ --out=C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\build6825805865501307423xxx\ApplicationCN1\ApplicationCN1\src --target=csharp --app-name=ApplicationCN1 [01/19/16 23:47:19.038]    ERROR: Couldn't create node for com.codename1.impl.ImplementationFactory
[01/19/16 23:47:19.038]    ERROR: Couldn't create node for com.codename1.impl.ImplementationFactory

...classes...
...lots of warnings about hidden inherited members...

"C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\build6825805865501307423xxx\ApplicationCN1\ApplicationCN1.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\build6825805865501307423xxx\ApplicationCN1\ApplicationCN1\ApplicationCN1.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
(CoreCompile target) -> 
  src\com\yyy\yyy\DialogForm.cs(1133,5): error CS1511: Keyword 'base' is not available in a static method [C:\Users\Shai\AppData\Local\Temp\build6825805865501307423xxx\ApplicationCN1\ApplicationCN1\ApplicationCN1.csproj]

    130875 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:07:44.77
```

My configuration:

```
Windows 7 SP1 x64;
Java SE Development Kit 7 Update 45 (64-bit);
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2), Build id: 20150219-0600;
Plugin: CodenameOneFeature 1.0.0.201511241324;
```

Contents of my `codenameone_settings.properties`:

```
#
#Mon Jan 18 16:05:13 EET 2016
codename1.vendor=yyy
codename1.displayName=yyy
codename1.icon=icon.png
codename1.languageLevel=5
codename1.secondaryTitle=yyy
codename1.version=0.4
codename1.mainName=ApplicationCN1
codename1.ios.certificatePassword=
codename1.rim.signtoolDb=
libVersion=97
codename1.ios.certificate=
codename1.arg.j2me.nativeThemeConst=3
codename1.arg.ios.add_libs=CFNetwork.framework
codename1.arg.android.debug=false
codename1.arg.android.release=true
codename1.j2me.nativeTheme=
codename1.rim.signtoolCsk=
codename1.rim.certificatePassword=
codename1.ios.provision=
codename1.packageName=com.yyy.yyy
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a field or method named `base` and our old XMLVM based backend isn't smart enough to deal with that (reserved word in C#).

Just rename that for now and also look at the project size.

We are currently working on a rewrite of the Windows Phone VM/port so this and many other issues won't exist when we are done. Since its almost a complete rewrite (we will probably base it in part on the [community port](https://github.com/Pmovil/CN1WindowsPort)) this might take a while to deliver.

Comment: I've checked for any occurrence of the "base" word in my code before asking this question.
It seems that the problem is more likely linked to using "super" keyword in static methods.
Is it possible to receive generated `src\com\yyy\yyy\DialogForm.cs` for my build?
Thanks for your great work!

Comment: Its possible, the XMLVM C# port is quite problematic. Unfortunately getting the sources of failed builds is pretty hard to do since we have a lot of deep assumptions in the project code against that. Its something that we need to do at some point and I think there is an RFE for that in the issue tracker.